# Colly not finding the body tag by xpath but finding it by selector name

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I'm learning web scraping using gocolly. When I try to find the  tag using selector name `body`, it successfully finds it. However, when I try to find the body tag by xpath `/html/body`, it fails to find it.

I have used OnHTML() with a simple callback function:

```
collector.OnHTML("/html/body", func(element *colly.HTMLElement) {

    fmt.Println("Found Body")

})
```

Any idea as to why is this happening?

Also, when looking at tutorials, I noticed that the selector passed into the function OnHTML() is sometimes wrapped by ""(double quotes) and sometimes by ``(back-ticks). Is there a difference between the two?

How do I search for a ID element because when I'm trying to search for the ID #layout-container under the body, Colly is not finding it:

```
collector.OnHTML("#layout-container", func(element *colly.HTMLElement) { 

    fmt.Println("Found Layout Container") 

})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From an HTML perspective, the `/html` part is already implied when using OnHTML.

You would use `/html/body`, as shown in [`colly_test.go`](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/blob/19b3ce62c774973a898eea3063c962aea206ec19/colly_test.go#L1148-L1163), with [OnXML()](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/blob/19b3ce62c774973a898eea3063c962aea206ec19/colly.go#L886-L899) (Function will be executed on every XML element matched by the xpath Query parameter)

The [test using OnHTML](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/blob/19b3ce62c774973a898eea3063c962aea206ec19/colly_test.go#L516-L524) shows only "`body`".

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense! I have one more doubt, does Colly only look for elements (selectors, ID's, classes etc) under the body or anywhere on the page? And, how do I search for a ID element because when I'm trying to search for the ID #layout-container under the body, Colly is not finding it:

```
collector.OnHTML("#layout-container", func(element *colly.HTMLElement) {
   fmt.Println("Found Layout Container")
  })
```

Comment: @kkin You can try and collect ID, filtering the one you want: https://github.com/gocolly/colly/blob/19b3ce62c774973a898eea3063c962aea206ec19/colly_test.go#L328-L340